# How to solve maximum likelihood estimates with inequality constraint?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

For example, let $ r_i \sim \operatorname{Binomial} (n, p_i)$, where $i \in [1,m]$. Assume that $ r_i $ are independent and also, put an inequality, $ p_1 < p_2 < \cdots < p_m $.

How to find the maximum likelihood estimates of $ p_1, \ldots,p_m$ in such setting?

I know the joint likelihood can be written as,

$$ \sum_{i=1}^m \big(r_{i} \log p_{i} + (n-r_{i})\log(1-p_{i})\big)+ \text{constant}.$$

But how can I continue to derive the MLE with the constraint?

Comment: If you're looking for a point in the space $\{\,(p_1,\ldots,p_n) : 0 \le p_1 < p_2 < \cdots < p_m\le 1\}$ that maximizes a likelihood function, there may not be one since in some cases the maximizing value will be on the boundary. Thus you may want to look in the space $\{\,(p_1,\ldots,p_n) : 0 \le p_1 \le p_2 \le \cdots \le p_m\le 1\}. \qquad$

Comment: I've deleted my answer. I may edit it further and then undelete it.

Comment: yep, i make a mistake.

Comment: An MLE is always within the closure of the parameter space, so the MLE must satisfy the same weak inequalities.

Comment: So, if it is the non-strict inequality, for example m = 2, then the MLE of p1 is r1/n, p2 = r2/n if r1 < r2 and p1 = p2 = r2/n if r2< r1. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Constrained maximum-likelihood is just a particular application of constrained optimisation more generally, and so it falls within the field of [nonlinear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_programming).  There are many methods of solving nonlinear optimisation problems constrained by inequality constraints, including the [Karush–Kuhn–Tucker method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) or simply transforming the problem into an unconstrained one.

**An example applicable to your problem:** In the present case, it is possible to transform the constrained vector $\boldsymbol{p} = (p_1, \ldots, p_m)$ from an unconstrained vector $\boldsymbol{u} = (u_1, \ldots, u_m) \in \mathbb{R}^m$.  There are lots of ways to do this, but one way is to define the transformation using nested [logistic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) as follows (the parameter $\alpha$ is a control parameter):

$$p_k = T_k(\boldsymbol{u}) \equiv \frac{1}{1 + \sum_{i=k}^m \exp(- \alpha u_i)} \quad \quad \text{for } k = 1,2,\ldots,m.$$

This yields a transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{ \boldsymbol{p} \in \mathbb{R}^m \mid 0 < p_1 < \cdots < p_m < 1 \}$, which means that it maps an unconstrained parameter $\boldsymbol{u}$ to the constrained parameter $\boldsymbol{p}$.  (I have also allowed for a control parameter $\alpha$ that lets you adjust the steepness of the logistic functions; you can remove this part by setting $\alpha = 1$ if you want to.)

Re-parameterising your optimisation problem into the new unconstrained parameter $\boldsymbol{u}$ yields the log-likelihood function (which also includes the logistic control parameter $\alpha$):

$$\ell_\boldsymbol{r}(\boldsymbol{u} \mid \alpha) = \sum_{k=1}^m \Big( (n_k-r_k) \log \Big( \sum_{i=k}^m \exp(- \alpha u_i) \Big) - n_k \log \Big(1 + \sum_{i=k}^m \exp(- \alpha u_i) \Big) \Big).$$

The maximum-likelihood estimator $\hat{\boldsymbol{u}}$ can be obtained by maximising this function over the unconstrained space $\boldsymbol{u} \in \mathbb{R}^m$, which requires numerical methods.  If this MLE exists, we then obtain the corresponding MLE for your desired parameter vector as $\hat{\boldsymbol{p}} = T(\hat{\boldsymbol{u}}, \alpha)$.

**Note:** In your problem the strict inequality constraints mean that the MLE will not exist for most data vectors.  If you change these to non-strict inequality constraints then the constrained MLE will exist.  In this case the transformation does not allow values with equality between adjacent $p_k$ values, but it allows you to come arbitrarily close to this.  Hence, standard numerical methods to maximise the above likelihood should still converge towards the MLE.

Comment: So, if it is the non-strict inequality, for example m = 2, then the MLE of p1 is r1/n, p2 = r2/n if r1 < r2 and p1 = p2 = r2/n if r2< r1. Am I right?